# Magento pricing with custom options to set new base price

Tags: magento-1.9, price

I'm trying to find a solution for some complex pricing in Magento.

Example:

Product price is $200

- first option is size. For example I choose size "large" which adds $50. The added value from the size option makes the new base price.
  So $200 + $50 = $250 (this is the new base price)
- Every next option price (percent or fixed) must be added to the new base price
- Next option color, I choose "green" which adds 10%. So $250 + 10% of $250 = $275
- Next option is material, I choose "leather" which adds another 10%. So $275 + 10% of $250 = $300.

Can anyone point me into the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

You should create a configurable product based on the first attribute (e.g. size). And for the next options (e.g. color, leather, ...), create custom options. The prices of the custom options will be based on the final price from the configurable product.

Drawback: You will not be able to set percentage pricing on custom options for configurable products.

I created a [sample product](https://iwdagency.com/magento2/test-product1.html).

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but I need to use percentage pricing.